# set default value to column of different column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Recently someone asked me, suppose there is table emp with column first name, lastname, fullname.

Question is how to insert into fullname if query is as below.

```
INSERT INTO emp ( firstname , lastname)
SELECT fname, lname
```

Please help

Comment: You use a computed column. `fullname AS fname + ' ' + lname`, for example. Or just use a view instead.

Answer (score 0):

Make `FullName` a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE Emp
   DROP COLUMN FullName

ALTER TABLE emp
   ADD FullName AS (FirstName + ' ' + LastName)
```

If either `FirstName` or `LastName` is nullable, you will have to modify the formula to handle it.

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO emp ( firstname , lastname, fullname)
SELECT fname, lname, fname + ' ' + lname
```

Comment: Thanks, computed column